# Issues with reactiveValues() and observe in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a shiny app where I define a "Parameters" `reactiveValues()` with a list of parameters that are needed for later calculations. I was working for a couple of weeks  so far so good but suddenly it begin to crash in an `observe()` function where some values are passed to Parameters (the other parameters are defined in other places). The observer is this:

```
  observe({
    # Other important parameters
    Parameters$Nsamp    <- 10
    Parameters$nit      <- 2500     
    Parameters$tolsigma <- 1e-4     
    Parameters$trl      <- 0
  })
```

This code triggers the following error.

```
Warning: Error in : `x` must be 'data.frame', not 'double'.
  58: stop
  57: stop_glue
  56: check_type
  55: specify
  48: observe
  47: server [C:\Users\.../app.R#255]
Error : `x` must be 'data.frame', not 'double'.
```

I've "solved" this problem by including those parameters when I define the list. This works, but I will include later some inputs that allows the user to define those parameters.

`Parameters <- reactiveValues(Nsamp = 10, nit = 2500, tolsigma = 1e-4, trl = 0)`

Comment: You should include a minimal reproducible example. I don't believe that error is in reference to shiny.  `specify` seems to be where to look

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your comment guide me to look in the new packages that I've installed in the last days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SmokeyShakers said, the problem was not in shiny. Thanks to that comment, I finally could solve the issue. The fact was that a couple of days ago I've installed the `tidymodels` package. This includes the `infer` package in which exist an `observe()` function. So, when I've used this function was the `infer::observe()` instead of the `shiny::observe()`.